# Single page application in devexpress asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

i am using devexpress in my application.
i want to navigate between menu by SPA.
i have tried this but its not SPA.

```
        @Html.DevExpress().Menu(settings =>
   {
       settings.Name = "Menu";
       settings.AllowSelectItem = false;
       settings.Orientation = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Orientation.Horizontal;

       settings.Items.Add(item =>
       {

           item.Items.Add(subItem =>
           {
               subItem.Text = "Flights";
               subItem.Items.Add("Create Flight", "", "", "../Home/Index");
               subItem.Items.Add("Services", "", "", "../Home/Service");
           });
           item.Items.Add("SubItem 1");
       });
       settings.Items.Add("Item 1");
   }).GetHtml()
```

how can i emplement SPA apps in devexpress asp.net mvc 5?

Comment: You can use single layout page and single view with action method returning different partial views in the same view. Show more what have you've tried to build SPA.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have a controller with two action.and for each action i have view and for every view has partial view.
how i can switch with navigations between one view thats has two partial view?